# Issue refreshing data inside didInsertElement

Tags: javascript, ember.js, datatables

I'm having an issue refreshing data inside didInsertElement in a view. I'm calling a model and getting the data (it's being queried from an API) and then loading it into a library (data tables) within didInsertElement. However, once I delete a record the data from the model is outdated and needs to be called again and put into the didInsertElement.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you initializing any thirdparty in didInsertElement hook ???

Comment: @selva-G Yes. I'm using DataTables and putting the data from the model in it. I need to have a way to update that data that is going into DataTables.

Answer (score 0):

If you are manually modifying the dom (or injecting into some third party element) and not using handlebars/ember the observers won't be setup which trigger and update the dom when the underlying model changes.  You'll need to set up some observers on the data and manually update the data as you see the data changing.